# ConfUserEx excluding a namespace from obfuscation

Tags: c#, obfuscation

In ConfUserEX Obfuscation (https://yck1509.github.io/ConfuserEx/)

How to **EXCLUDE** just one Namespace from rename module?

For example :
`[assembly: Obfuscation(Exclude = true, Feature = "namespace 'ABC.XYZ':-rename")]`

Looks it does not work. I have a objectmodels for Json parsing in a namespace and this throwing error. Also I am using .crproj file for obfuscating using CLI.

Comment: Thanks, I will follow !

Answer (score 5):

Please download latest version v0.6.0 by [this](https://github.com/yck1509/ConfuserEx/releases%20and%20also%20change%20value%20of%20the) link. Exclude field from `true` to `false`. And that's it.

For example:

```
[assembly: Obfuscation(Exclude = false, Feature = "namespace 'Your.Namespace':-rename")]
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/yck1509/ConfuserEx/wiki/Declarative-Obfuscation) , if you want to exclude a namespace, the correct way to do it is to write a line like:

```
[assembly: Obfuscation(Exclude = false, Feature = "namespace('namespaceToExclude'):-rename")]
```

This should be written in the **Assembly.info** file of the project.