# How to use GetMethod in my own class obfuscated by ConfuserEx?

Tags: c#, reflection, getmethod, confuserex

I have my own DLL which I secure with ConfuserEx.
In the ConfuserEx I'm using the "rename" protection:

```
<protection id="rename">
    <argument name="mode" value="unicode" />
    <argument name="renEnum" value="true" />        
</protection>
```

This of course secures the DLL from viewing the code, but my class (which I have secured as part of a DLL), uses:

```
MethodInfo mi = typeof(MyClass).GetMethod(nameof(MyStaticMethod), BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

Here the problem starts, because **even my own code cannot find and use my** (protected by ConfuserEx) **method**. I use GetMethod to call: Delegate.CreateDelegate. What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Why are you needing to use reflection to access your own assembly's members?

Comment: Because I use an external class that has a delegate, and I want to be connected to it so that my method will be called.

Comment: If the method is meant to be called by an external class, you should probably [exclude it from obfuscation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29940328/confuserex-excluding-a-namespace-from-obfuscation).

Comment: You can create a delegate to a private/internal method and pass that to another assembly just fine without reflection. The accessibility check is done at the point the delegate instance is created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still not sure why you can't just create the delegate you need directly without reflection, but if you really *need* to get the `MethodInfo`, try doing something like this:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thingy t = DoStuff;
        var mi = t.Method;
    }
    private delegate void Thingy(object sender, EventArgs e);
    private static void DoStuff(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

That is, use your own locally defined delegate that matches the other delegate definition, create an instance of it directly in your code and then extract the `MethodInfo` from that instance.

This code will be using a method token to identify `DoStuff` rather than its name so should survive obfuscation without issue.

Comment: It looks like we came up with a similar idea :) Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by applying an additional "bridge delegate" between GetMethod and the target method. Then, instead of nameof (MyStaticMethod), I use BridgeDelegate.Method.Name. I checked and works correctly.

**Example solution:**

```
internal static class MyClass
{
    private delegate void ExecuteObfuscatedMethod(string value);
    private static ExecuteObfuscatedMethod Bridge; //This is my "bridge"

    internal static void CaptureExternalDelegate(object source)
    {
        //Using a "bridge" instead of the direct method name
        MethodInfo mi = typeof(MyClass).GetMethod(Bridge.Method.Name, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        //Less interesting code
        PropertyInfo p = source.GetType().GetProperty("SomePrivateDelegate", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        Delegate del = Delegate.CreateDelegate(p.PropertyType, mi) as Delegate;
        Delegate original = p.GetValue(source) as Delegate;
        Delegate combined = Delegate.Combine(original, del);
        p.SetValue(property, combined);
    }

    static MyClass()
    {
        Bridge += MyStaticMethod;
    }

    //This is the method whose name can not be retrieved by nameof () after applying ConfuserEx
    private static void MyStaticMethod(string value)
    {
        //I am testing the method's name after calling it.
        var st = new StackTrace();
        var sf = st.GetFrame(0);
        var currentMethodName = sf.GetMethod();
        throw new Exception("The method name is: " + currentMethodName); //You can see that the method has evoked and you can even see its new name
    }
}
```